# multiple definition error in Clion

Tags: c, compiler-errors, c-preprocessor

I added "[Mersenne Twist Pseudorandom Number Generator Package](https://www.cs.hmc.edu/~geoff/mtwist.html)" (one header file and one source file) to my Clion `C` project, but I can not build the project.
the error is :

```
multiple definition of `mts_lrand'
```

I can successfully compile and run the program using just command line and `gcc` but in Clion i can not.

I think it has something to do with macros, but I do not know how to fix it.

here is some part of the code i added:

**mtwist.h**

```
.
.
.
.
/*
 * In gcc, inline functions must be declared extern or they'll produce
 * assembly code (and thus linking errors).  We have to work around
 * that difficulty with the MT_EXTERN define.
 */
#ifndef MT_EXTERN
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define MT_EXTERN           /* C++ doesn't need static */
#else /* __cplusplus */
#define MT_EXTERN   extern      /* C (at least gcc) needs extern */
#endif /* __cplusplus */
#endif /* MT_EXTERN */
/*
 * Make it possible for mtwist.c to disable the inline keyword.  We
 * use our own keyword so that we don't interfere with inlining in
 * C/C++ header files, above.
 */
#ifndef MT_INLINE
#define MT_INLINE   inline      /* Compiler has inlining */
#endif /* MT_INLINE */
/*
 * Try to guess whether the compiler is one (like gcc) that requires
 * inline code to be available in the header file, or a smarter one
 * that gets inlines directly from object files.  But if we've been
 * given the information, trust it.
 */
#ifndef MT_GENERATE_CODE_IN_HEADER
#ifdef __GNUC__
#define MT_GENERATE_CODE_IN_HEADER 1
#endif /* __GNUC__ */
#if defined(__INTEL_COMPILER)  ||  defined(_MSC_VER)
#define MT_GENERATE_CODE_IN_HEADER 0
#endif /* __INTEL_COMPILER || _MSC_VER */
#endif /* MT_GENERATE_CODE_IN_HEADER */
#if MT_GENERATE_CODE_IN_HEADER
/*
 * Generate a random number in the range 0 to 2^32-1, inclusive, working
 * from a given state vector.
 *
 * The generator is optimized for speed.  The primary optimization is that
 * the pseudorandom numbers are generated in batches of MT_STATE_SIZE.  This
 * saves the cost of a modulus operation in the critical path.
 */
MT_EXTERN MT_INLINE uint32_t mts_lrand(
    register mt_state*  state)      /* State for the PRNG */
    {
    register uint32_t   random_value;   /* Pseudorandom value generated */
    if (state->stateptr <= 0)
    mts_refresh(state);
    random_value = state->statevec[--state->stateptr];
    MT_PRE_TEMPER(random_value);
    return MT_FINAL_TEMPER(random_value);
    }
.
.
.
.
```

you see the function definition is in header file, i think this is the problem but I don't know what to do

you can see complete code [here](https://www.cs.hmc.edu/~geoff/mtwist.html).

Comment: A similar error I have I solved putting `#define MT_NO_INLINE` before the `#include`.